# How to re-install deleted add-on in owasp zap?

Tags: owasp, zap

I accidentally deleted ajax spider while managing the add-on in zap. So to re-install it, I went to marketpalce section, but it is not shown in the list. How can I install that add-on? Any help?

[listed add-on in marketplace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGRdA.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, we've just updated the Selenium add-on (which the Ajax Spider depends on) to support Selenium 3, which requires Java 8.
Are you using Java 7? If so that will be the problem. Can you update to Java 8?

Oh, and do check that you are running the latest version of ZAP (currently 2.6.0)

Comment: i have re-installed it instead :)